# How to prevent the parameter from raising error, if % is passed in rails parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

In my project, I used will_paginate gem for pagination. I rescue the standard error and redirect to another page, If unwanted parameter is found like characters and symbols (`params[:page]` (will_paginate gem's default page parameter)). `rescue StandardError` works perfectly for all parameters except %.

```
begin
@page = params[:page]
rescue StandardError
  redirect_to posts_index_path
end
```

If I passed the % as parameter, it will shows 400 error. Why this problem is happened. How to prevent it from showing this error.

Comment: Is that your actual code? I don't understand how a simple assignment could raise an StandardError, it's just an assignment of a string or nil.

Comment: @arieljuod I also think like you. But It shows 400 error. That's why I'm getting confused of it.

Comment: Show the whole action's code and the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: also, check this https://thomasleecopeland.com/2018/08/12/invalid-or-incomplete-post-parameters.html, maybe that's your actual error, the params parsing and not the asignment

Comment: @arieljuod Thank you for your response. I'm satisfied with your answer